# How to tell what kind of file from file string

Tags: image, file, binary-data

I have a file string i am unable to decode in order to retrieve an image. I am pretty sure its a UTF-8 string since it begins with 0xFF. It is definitely a hex value and its 259 characters long. I believe it is from a binary file dump from a MYSQL server column.

I'm very used to being able to retrieve Base64 image strings and pass them through imagemagick in order to create images, but when i was handed these image strings i was completely floored when someone told me these were whole files. 259 characters seems way to small, but i imagine i also may just be missing a kind of conversion pass to get the whole string.

"0xFFD8FFE1149F4578...1320002000000140000" (259 characters in length.)

Comment: How was the string stored? How is PHP related here?

Comment: Might be a jpeg https://filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=FFD8FFE1&mode=SIG

Comment: The file this column belongs to is exported as a CSV to me. This is the "picture" column in the SQL DB from my contacts understanding.

Comment: This is not a string, this is binary data encoded in hexadecimal numbers. Use a hexeditor and save a field value as a binary file as jpg as @JasonK suggested and see if it works.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with hex editors. Is there one you would recommend to be able to check this path out? It definitely sounds promising. I'll have to figure out how to then do this in PHP in order to render an image through a script.

Comment: Search for `magic FFD8`

Comment: I'll continue to look for hex editors to be able to transform this string. The few i saw online didn't really do anything that i could understand. I found this snippet in PHP i attempted, but it doesn't believe the string is hex.

<?php    
        $hexpic="FFD8FFE1149F4578696600...1000180140000"; //Not showing whole string because of space.
        $data = hex2bin($hexpic);
        $fp = fopen('sample.jpg', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, $data);
 fclose($fp);
?>

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be what happens when you use MariaDB's [LOAD_FILE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/load_file/) into a varchar(259). The whole file is sent, but only the first 259 characters are saved. This turns out to be a lot less of understanding what kind of file, but instead what happens when you don't set your DB up with the correct column types. When I did this experiment with a LONGTEXT type. I was able to load files and select them again. Though they do end up going into a very strange sub directory inside MariaDB's etc folder with a temp folder.

All of your suggestions were dead on, just didn't have all of the data.

This is right from the [MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html):

"If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a CHAR or VARCHAR column that *exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is truncated to fit* and a warning is generated. For truncation of nonspace characters, you can cause an error to occur (rather than a warning) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode. See Section 5.1.11, “Server SQL Modes”."